# Iexpress.exe Unable to open report file even when ran as administrator

Tags: iexpress

I'm creating a Iexpress package, and no matter what on the final step it pops up the message "Unable to open report file" and stops. I am searching Iexpress.exe and right clicking, then choosing "Run As Administrator" to start it. The problem persists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to fix this problem:

1. Go to the folder where your files you want to be in the package are
2. Go to the top bar (Where it says where you are on your drive), and type `iexpress`
3. Do the creation as normal, but the names you give the installer shouldn't have any spaces.

I did it this way without admin permissions.

Answer (score 3):

I had this error running as my account (domain admin) not specifically telling it to run as administrator, removed spaces then re-ran working fine under Windows 10 1809 you shouldn't need to change to a different application to create .EXE files using IEXPRESS this is working fine under Window 10.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up moving on to Inno Setup Compiler. Turns out Iexpress isn't supported anymore. I recommend Inno to anyone making their own programs.

Answer (score 1):

This happens when `SourceFilesX` or `TargetName` paths in the directive (i.e. the files you've added from the wizard) contain spaces. And while the issue with the `TargetName` can be fixed with adding double quotes the only workaround I've found about the source files is to put them in a folder path that not contains spaces.